# Magento 1.7.0.2 database, modify Name on the Card

Tags: database, magento

One of our customers accidentally put his credit card number in the "Name on the Card" field and placed the order. Which field in the Magento database should I modify to change it?

Comment: Which payment module is in use for CC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table 
sales_flat_order_payment

Field 
cc_owner